# Não estou conseguindo validar o usuário autenticado

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

**PROBLEMA:** Não estou conseguindo validar o usuário autenticado pelo banco de dados.
O que acontece é que quando rodo minha aplicação, colocando usuário e senha validos, o mesmo me retorna false dentro do meu loginOk localizado no HomeController.

**Detalhes do código**

MODAL: Nessa classe tenho um método ValidarLogin onde ele efetua uma verificação no banco para realizar a consulta.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    public bool ValidarLogin()
    {
        // Comando para fazer a consulta
        string consultaSql = $"Select VendedorId From Estudo.Vendedores Where Email='{Email}' and Senha='{Senha}'";
        DAL Acessar = new DAL();
        DataTable carregaTabela = new DataTable(consultaSql); // Comando para executar a consulta.

        if (carregaTabela.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

CLASSE DE CONEXÃO:

```
public class DAL
{
    // Variaveis de conexão
    private static string NomeServidor = @"DESKTOP-DC0D3FT\THIAGO";
    private static string TipoAutenticacao = "SSPI";
    private static string NomeBanco = "SistemaDeVenda";
    private static string StringConexao = $"Data source={NomeServidor}; Integrated Security={TipoAutenticacao}; Initial Catalog={NomeBanco}" ;
    private static SqlConnection Conexao;


    //@"data source=DESKTOP-DC0D3FT\THIAGO; Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SistemaDeVenda"

    public DAL()

    {
        Conexao = new SqlConnection(StringConexao);
        Conexao.Open();
    }

    public DataTable RetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand Executar = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexao);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Executar);
        da.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }

    public void ExecutarComandoSQL(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand Executar = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexao );
        Executar.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


}
```

Home Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginModel login)
    {
        bool loginOk = login.ValidarLogin();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Se realizar a consulta (pegando no resultado da variável `consultaSql`) no SQL devolve o valor correto?

Comment: Você tem certeza de quer fazer isso na ViewModel?

Comment: Ps.: O problema não é porque está retornando para a View Login sem transportar a ViewModel?